# Bulma progress text in middle

Tags: progress-bar, bulma

Why when I use progress from Bulma CSS framework [(https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/progress/)](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/progress/)

and I put text between tags, I don't see any value.

`<progress class="progress is-danger" value="90" max="100">90%</progress>`

How add text on middle on progress in Bulma?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's **normal** that you don't see the value

```html
<progress value="90" max="100">90%</progress>
```

There is **no** built-in solution.

But according to [show-a-progress-bars-value-number-like-55-on-the-bar-by-using-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964214/show-a-progress-bars-value-number-like-55-on-the-bar-by-using-css) the following is a **solution**

```css
progress.show-value {
  position: relative;
}

progress.show-value:after {
  content: attr(value)'%';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: calc(1rem / 1.5);
  line-height: 1rem;
}

progress.show-value.is-small:after {
  font-size: calc(0.75rem / 1.5);
  line-height: 0.75rem;
}

progress.show-value.is-medium:after {
  font-size: calc(1.25rem / 1.5);
  line-height: 1.25rem;
}

progress.show-value.is-large:after {
  font-size: calc(1.5rem / 1.5);
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<progress class="progress is-danger is-small show-value" value="90" max="100">90%</progress>
<progress class="progress is-danger show-value" value="90" max="100">90%</progress>
<progress class="progress is-danger is-medium show-value" value="90" max="100">90%</progress>
<progress class="progress is-danger is-large show-value" value="90" max="100">90%</progress>
```

### UPDATE

The solution above does not work on Firefox!

Here is an **overall solution**:

```css
.progress-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.progress-value {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: calc(1rem / 1.5);
  line-height: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.progress.is-small+.progress-value {
  font-size: calc(0.75rem / 1.5);
  line-height: 0.75rem;
}

.progress.is-medium+.progress-value {
  font-size: calc(1.25rem / 1.5);
  line-height: 1.25rem;
}

.progress.is-large+.progress-value {
  font-size: calc(1.5rem / 1.5);
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="progress-wrapper">
  <progress class="progress is-danger is-small" value="90" max="100">90%</progress>
  <p class="progress-value has-text-white">90%</p>
</div>
<div class="progress-wrapper">
  <progress class="progress is-danger" value="90" max="100">90%</progress>
  <p class="progress-value has-text-white">90%</p>
</div>
<div class="progress-wrapper">
  <progress class="progress is-danger is-medium" value="90" max="100">90%</progress>
  <p class="progress-value has-text-white">90%</p>
</div>
<div class="progress-wrapper">
  <progress class="progress is-danger is-large" value="90" max="100">90%</progress>
  <p class="progress-value has-text-white">90%</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Currently on Firefox 64 it does nothing.