# How do I put text into a progress bar in HTML5 with bulma?

Tags: css, html, bulma

By default, what you put in between the `<progress></progress>` tags will not show.

```html
<progress class="progress" value="15" max="100">15%</progress>
```

How would I get the 15% to show? I am using Bulma as a framework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bulma progress text in middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400219/bulma-progress-text-in-middle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use pseudo element and data attribute [(works only on chrome ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162649/css-content-attr-on-html5-progress-doesnt-work)

```css
.progress:before {
  content:attr(data-text);
}
.progress {
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<progress class="progress" value="15" max="100" data-text="15%"></progress>
```

Or you can simply consider an extra wrapper:

```css
.progress:before {
  content:attr(data-text);
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
.progress {
 text-align:center;
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress" data-text="15%"><progress  value="15" max="100" ></progress></div>
```

Including bulma:

```css
.progress-container:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  line-height:1em;
}

.progress-container {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="progress-container" data-text="15%"><progress class="progress" value="15" max="100"></progress></div>
```

Comment: @OskarSherrah yes only on chrome ... I trying to figure out a solution for others

Comment: @OskarSherrah updated with another solution .. probably not the best but it works

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work for me, it just made a white space, and after inspecting the output, I didn't see the text there in case it was in white font.

Comment: @OskarSherrah you are talking about the second solution I shared, right?

Comment: @OskarSherrah I see the second solution works on Firefox also.

Comment: @TemaniAfif ah sorry didn't see one of the changes. It works, but it is altering the length of my progress bar..

Comment: @OskarSherrah probably due to the use of `inline-block`, try without

Comment: @TemaniAfif That fixed it! But the formatting is a bit off

https://i.imgur.com/4VPY1Im.png
The way it is supposed to look is on the left..

Comment: @OskarSherrah give some margin to the extra wrapper something like `margin-bottom:20px`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you `progress` with `div` and add `span`

(I did not use `:after/before` and it has to work in all browser)

[See fiddle using bulma](https://jsfiddle.net/pd2zw4th/3/)

```
<div>
<span>
  15%
</span>
<progress  class="progress" value="15" max="100" >

</progress>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
span{
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```