# Display a DOM element over <progress> element

Tags: html, css

I have a `<progress>` element being used as a progress bar. I would like to display some `<div>`s on top of the progress bar, but they do not appear. They appear if I use a `<div>` (with jQuery-ui progressbar) instead of the `<progress>` element, but I would like to avoid this if possible. Does anyone know of a solution?

I have already tried setting `z-index: -1`, which did not work.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#progressbar").click(function(event) {
    var posX = $(this).offset().left;
    posX = (event.pageX - posX) / $("#progressbar").width() * 100;
    $("#progressbar").val(posX);
  })
});
```

```css
.ball {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

#progressbar {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

#left-ball {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  left: calc(25% - 5px);
}

#right-ball {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  left: calc(75% - 5px);
}

#line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  right: 25%;
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
}

.delete {
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <progress id="progressbar" value="50" max="100">
    <div class="delete ball" id="left-ball"></div>
    <div class="delete line" id="line"></div>
    <div class="delete ball" id="right-ball"></div>
  </progress>
</body>
```

Comment: hello, insert your html, css and jquery, pls

Comment: Done, thanks for the reminder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display data label inside HTML5 progress bar cross-browser compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429906/how-to-display-data-label-inside-html5-progress-bar-cross-browser-compatible) Later in the answer it mentions that `<progress>` is a replaced element, so anything inside it is removed.

Comment: It does, thanks! darn :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They appear if I use a  (with jQuery-ui progressbar) instead of
> the  element, but I would like to avoid this if possible.

If you absolutely must have these elements inside of a "progress bar", you may opt to use some custom markup & CSS to achieve it. It is not possible with a `progress` element because it behaves like a replaced element. It differs from the `input` element though, for example, in that the `progress` element has a closing tag. This is taken advantage of.

A common technique for global browser support is that you would initially have a `progress` element as a parent and inside of it is some fallback mark up that will be rendered by older browsers instead of the `progress` element. The old browsers will ignore the `progress` element because it simply does not support it.

```
<progress id="progressbar" value="50" max="100">
  <div id="fallback-progressbar">50%</div>
</progress>
```